# Check if iCloud has two-factor authentication? Swift/iOS

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, cloudkit

Is there a way to check if a user's iCloud account has two-factor authentication enabled?

I am adding iCloud functionality to my app using CloudKit and for added security I'd like to perform this check and recommend the user enable two-factor if it isn't already.

I already check if the user is logged into iCloud on app load, but have been unable to find any guidance about performing this additional check. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to check if a user's iCloud account has two-factor authentication enabled?

**No**, by design - and there shouldn't be.

A representative from the Apple Developer Relations team indicated as such on the Apple Developer Forums a few years ago ([original source](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/70549)), in response to what appears to be the OP here, actually:

> No.
>
> IMO it’s not your job to nag users about two-factor. Fortunately, I don’t get the make the call (-: so you should feel free to file an [enhancement request](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/) describing your use case so that CloudKit engineering can consider it.

In the iOS ecosystem, such a configuration decision is well outside the intended functionality scope for third-party applications. Having third-party apps complain about specific settings on your iCloud account would be confusing (at best) for end users.

If it doesn't directly affect the operation of your application, your app probably shouldn't be attempting to advise users on it.

Comment: I understand that it's difficult to prove a negative and your answer makes sense, but do you maybe have a source to corroborate?

Comment: @AgostBiro That's entirely fair criticism - completely slipped my mind to link to what I had been looking at - check the edit. Thanks for the call-out!